# How to decrypt the password which is encrypted by oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dbms-metadata

I want to decrypt the password which is encrypted by oracle 10g.

The encrypted password like
`'S:987DFSSDF9879SDFD80FSS0D8DFH8F0H77S;234SDFSF987FSDF34E'`

Comment: What algorithm was used to encrypt it? Was it actually encrypted or was it passed through a one-way hash? (If it was a one-way hash then you can't "decrypt" it!)

Comment: **WHY** would you want to decrypt a password (even assuming that would make sense, which it doesn't - passwords are hashed, not encrypted)? How do you have the "encrypted" value in the first place - where did you get it from?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: The OP should first explain WHY he wants to "decrypt" a password. That doesn't sound like a legitimate action.

Comment: You cannot decrypt it, it is hashed. The only thing you can do, is to copy the hashed value to another database, then you will also copy the users password - but you cannot decrypt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot decrypt it. It is not encrypted as such, it is a one-way hash.

You'll need to login as a privileged user and set the password for that user to something new.

Comment: I don't think someone "new to oracle" should be the privileged user who sets passwords for other users...